# How to make the default date format dd/mm/yyyy in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, import-from-excel

I have an Excel file that contains a column full of dates in the **dd/mm/yyyy** format. When I try to import it using openrowset, it said that there was a datatype mismatch. I have a table where the date is defined as type `date`. Now, I know that the default date format in SQL Server is **yyyy-mm-dd**. How can I avoid this conflict? Is there a way I can make the default `date` type be dd/mm/yyyy? I need to do this import operation everyday and it has to be automated and so I cannot afford it to fail in between. I tried using `sp_addlanguage` to make it British as the default date type is **dd/mm/yyyy** there, **but it didn't work :(. I'm using SQL Server 2008 and Windows 7, if that is of any help. Please help me out! Thanks!**

Comment: Would it help to change the date format in the excel file instead? or is that format ignored?

Comment: @Svish: That is a fixed format that will come from elsewhere which cannot be messed with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `CONVERT` the incoming data before you insert it. So, in the openrowset statement, where you select the field, you could surround it with a `CONVERT` statement. Here's an example:

```
print convert(date,'19/07/2010',103)
```

This is a UK style date, but if you run it you can see that it's converted it to SQL-friendly format.

Comment: @Tom: I have the following SQL query:  `SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;DATABASE=D:\Nemmadi Project\Dummy Bank Statement.xls', 'Select * from [Sheet1$]')`  Where should I add the `CONVERT` statement? Additionally, I could successfully insert it via a `bulk insert` when it was in a CSV format. The date in the file is of the format: 01/03/2011 (1st March 2011). I did: `set language 'british english'
bulk insert bank_report from 'D:\Nemmadi Project\Dummy Bank Statement.csv' with
(firstrow=2, maxerrors=0, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')`

Comment: @Tom: But when I view the table, the date was inserted as: 2011-03-01 00:00:00.000. What to do about this? While defining the table, when I tried to make the date column as a `DATE` type, the `BULLK INSERT` refused to work, working only when I made it `DATETIME`. Any workarounds?

Comment: Firstly, instead of selecting *, if you specify the actual rows (you'll see the names in the row header once you've done a *). Let's assume they are: Field1,Field2,Field3 and that Field2 is the date column. Then you can re-write the statement: SELECT Field1, CONVERT(date,Field2,103), Field3 FROM OPENROWSET...  This would be my preferred method, rather than messing with the language settings...but if it's working for you..

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for the tip! It works only when in the CSV format. Also, do you have any advice on the `DATETIME`/`DATE` conflict?

Comment: you should find that the CONVERT above will produce something that can go into either a date or datetime, I would have though. So it's odd that it doesn't. I'm getting a bit confused now.. which of the statements are you using now?

Comment: I got it! It was an xlsx file that I was trying to insert. It works fine with xls files. The only thing is now, I have to make the file "dynamic". I get a new file everyday and I need to insert it into a table. The file name might change everyday, but will have the same content. Also, how can I extend it to read the correct sheet? And last, how can I use openrowset to skip a few rows, take only a few columns, and read all columns between the first few skipped ones and a few that will be skipped at the end?

Comment: There's about 5 different questions in there! What I'd suggest is, close this question off by selecting an answer (this will help your answer rate as well, which is only at 50%) and then raise new questions for each individual problem. This will give your questions much more visibility and mean that you're much more likely to get a quick and accurate answer.